# Return an object from a function

Tags: r

How do I return an object from a function, rather than the output provided when you call the object?

```
best.mod <- function(d){
  m1 <- lm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width, d)
  m2 <- lm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width + I(Sepal.Width^2), d)
  ifelse(AIC(m1) < AIC(m2), m1, m2)
}

mod <- best.mod(iris[iris$Species == "setosa",])
class(mod)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem comes from using `ifelse`. This is meant for vectorised comparisons. A standard `if ... else` is better here:

```
best.mod <- function(d){
  m1 <- lm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width, d)
  m2 <- lm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width + I(Sepal.Width^2), d)
  if(AIC(m1) < AIC(m2)) return(m1) else return(m2)
}

mod <- best.mod(iris[iris$Species == "setosa",])
class(mod)
[1] "lm"
```

Note the warning from `?ifelse`:

> The mode of the result may depend on the value of test (see the
>   examples), and the class attribute (see oldClass) of the result is
>   taken from test and may be inappropriate for the values selected from
>   yes and no.

Comment: I think @James just got there first.  Thank you both - I didn't know that about `ifelse`

Comment: I think it's simpler and better without `return`, like this:`if(AIC(m1) < AIC(m2)) m1 else m2`

Answer (score 3):

`ifelse` is not really meant for this kind of usage, simply use `if` and `else` for this:

```
best.mod <- function(d){
  m1 <- lm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width, d)
  m2 <- lm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width + I(Sepal.Width^2), d)
  if(AIC(m1) < AIC(m2)) m1 else m2
}

mod <- best.mod(iris[iris$Species == "setosa",])
class(mod)
```

`ifelse` is meant for this kind of things:

```
vec = runif(100)
ifelse(vec < 0.5, NA, vec)
```